# MySQL Select where date = curdate() OR duedate = exactly 14 days from now

Tags: mysql, date, select, intervals

I need to write a query I cant quite figure out yet.

I have a table with 2 dates. One of them is the date of creation and the other one is the date of return. I want to select all rows

`WHERE date_creation = CURDATE() OR date_return = exactly 14 days ahead.` It doesn't have to be precise by the hour since it's a cronjob and runs once a day.

I have tried using `INTERVAL + - DAYS,` etc. But seems like INTERVAL selects everything that falls WITHIN that range. I need something exact.

Hope someone can help me on my way.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you can use this 
WHERE date_creation = CURDATE() OR date_return = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY);

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate
```

Comment: Note that for performance it might be better to do this as 2 queries unioned together to allow MySQL to use its indexes

Comment: Cool! I always thought interval was a range kind of thing. Many thanks =)